# correlation plot (Corrplot heatmap) where showing significance level but row and column will be be different (selected)?

Tags: r, limit, heatmap, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to plot a correlation heatmap by using corrplot package. [Details](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) can be found here. But my question is if I want to limit the row and column name where we need the modification?

Row name

> mpg    cyl    disp   hp     drat

Column name

> wt     qsec   vs     am     gear   carb

Data `M = cor(mtcars)`

`corrplot(M, p.mat = testRes$p, method = 'color', diag = FALSE, type = 'upper', sig.level = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), pch.cex = 0.9,  insig = 'label_sig', pch.col = 'grey20', order = 'AOE')`

Figure should be look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial solution.

```
library(corrplot)
library(Hmisc)    # Computes correlation and p-value matrix
Mp <- rcorr(as.matrix(mtcars))
corrplot(Mp$r[1:5, 6:11], p.mat=Mp$P[1:5, 6:11], method="color", addCoef.col="black")
```

produces a plot with the correlation coefficients.

```
corrplot(Mp$r[1:5, 6:11], p.mat=Mp$P[1:5, 6:11], method="color", sig.level = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), insig = 'label_sig')
```

produces a plot that labels the significance of the coefficients. I have not seen a way to combine both so that they do not overprint. Several of your arguments: method = 'color', diag = FALSE, type = 'upper', order = 'AOE' are not appropriate for non-symmetrical plots.

[image: Corrplots]

Comment: I added a [quick way to combine correlation coefficients and significance stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695113/changing-the-position-of-the-signifigance-pch-symbols-in-corrplot/69557793#69557793) without overprint.